# Same Instance number for two DICOM Image in a Single Series

Tags: dicom, modality

I have two **images** from the same series but both image has same **Instance Number** as 6. Is it Possible???? upto my understanding in a series instance number will be unique for an image in that series. So please help me... in any case is it possible from modality workstation ????

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the General Image Module in PS 3.3 section C.7.6.1, you will notice that Instance Number (0020, 0013) is a Type 2 element.  That means it can be empty. So, you should not count for it to be unique at the image/instance level.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible and 100% legal DICOM.  The only instance level unique value is the SOP Instance UID.

Comment: thanks for your reply... but How come it is possible ??? The study's images are sorted by instance number. Instance 1 - first image, instance 2-second image.... then how come 6th and 7th image has same instance number has 6.

Comment: There are many possible reasons why this happened - impossible to say without knowing more information about the study.